# PHP sleep() For Specific Block of Code

Tags: php, for-loop, sleep, continue, usleep

I need to delay the `continue` statement of a loop I am running by a certain number of microseconds. However, I want the rest of the loop to run, and then I just want it to stop running and `continue` when the time is up, even if some things in the loop are left undone. I know this code does not work, but this is what I am envisioning:

```
for ($_x = 0; $_x < 10; $_x++){
    usleep (1000){
        continue;
    }

    // ... do other stuff here until timer is up

    // when the timer runs out, continue to the next iteration
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't figure out what this means. `continue` skips the rest of the loop body and goes to the next iteration.

Comment: real code or the real world problem would help explain this

Comment: Why not just put the `Continue` after the other code?

Comment: I just need the code in the loop to run normally, and then once the time is up, `continue` to the next iteration without waiting for the entire loop body to finish running.

Comment: wrap the for loop in a while, using a timmer to know when to move on ?

Comment: The reason I don't want to put `continue` after the other code is because the code takes fairly long, so I just want to `continue` out if it happens to take over 1 second.

Comment: I think I've figured it out. You want to cancel the rest of the loop body if it takes more than 1000 microseconds.

Comment: is there a spot in the loop you expect to find the limit reached? Might be easier to answer with the real loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what you want. i've converted to to sleep 1 instead of usleep to prove it works, but if you switch it back it accomplishes what you want. you're welcome.

```
function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

for ($_x = 1; $_x < 11; $_x++) {
    $_m = microtime_float();
    $_v = sleep(1);
    $_n = microtime_float();
    do{
        //script here
        echo "<hr></br>".$_m."</br>".$_n ."</br>" .$_x;
    }
    while($_v);
}
```

the output

1396497686.9354
1396497687.9356
1

1396497687.9357
1396497688.9363
2

1396497688.9364
1396497689.937
3

1396497689.9371
1396497690.9381
4

1396497690.9381
1396497691.9392
5

1396497691.9393
1396497692.9398
6

1396497692.9399
1396497693.9406
7

1396497693.9406
1396497694.9415
8

1396497694.9415
1396497695.9424
9

1396497695.9424
1396497696.9427
10

Comment: `sleep` returns `Returns zero on success, or FALSE on error.`

Comment: while sleep(1) === true, do{//shit here} pretty much as close as you'll get without using threads or some convoluted use of eval

Comment: If I understand the OP he wants if the current looping execution takes longer than a second to continue not every iteration. Also sleep never turns `TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

Try [PHP Threads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php)

> When the start method of a Thread is invoked, the run method code will be executed in separate Thread, asynchronously.

Comment: perhaps it is what he wants, but i really dont think so.

Comment: I agree. I don't think he knows what he needs, just what he wants.

Comment: I would assume this is close to what he wants, running in the background.  However, I feel like he is running this from CLI anyways, so it might make more sense to just run whatever he needs to using a shell_exec('nohup ... &').  If on linux atleast.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you want to do something like:

```
$time = time() + 1;
for($_x = 0; $_x < 10 && $time > time(); $_x++){}
```

OR

```
$time = time() + 1;
for($_x = 0; $_x < 10; $_x++){
    if($time > time()){
        continue;
    }
}
```

OR maybe? add `if($time > time(){continue;}` to several places like

```
function too_long($time){
    if($time > time()){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}

for($_x = 0; $_x < 10; $_x++){
    $time = time() + 1;
    //block of code
    if(too_long($time)){
        continue;
    }
    //block of code
    if(too_long($time)){
        continue;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's quite it, he wants to break the loop, the way you have it , the loop will finish the current iteration